# Kill long running pipeline automatically in GoCD

Tags: continuous-delivery, go-cd

Is it possible to automatically kill long running pipeline in GoCD, if taking more time than anticipated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Specify default job timeout at the server level and also at the job level, see [Job Timeout](https://docs.gocd.io/16.2.0/configuration/job_timeout.html) for details.

> You must be logged in as an admin user to configure this step.
>
> - Navigate to the Admin section on the Go dashboard.
> - Navigate to Server configuration
> - Navigate to the pipeline management sub-section

[image]

Or

> You must be logged in as an admin user to configure this step.
>
> - Navigate to the Admin section on the Go dashboard.
> - Navigate to the job settings page for the job.

[image]